# List appending during loop seems to be optimized out in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a client-server application, with the client gathering some information, and having it json serialized and sent to the server, who will later store it in a database. In the server's tcp serving module, I have code that loads json objects from strings in a list and then appends them to another list like this (look at the loop inside `bind_and_listen`, which begins with `for client in clients`):

```
""" TCP Server before the main database. """

import socket
import sys
import logging
import json

import structs.client_data as cl_data
import db.register as register

cursor = register.cursor

client_list = []
domain_list = []

# connection constants
HOST = None
PORT = None


def config_server(host, port):
    """ Configure the server's address and port. """
    if not host:
       logging.warning("HOST not supplied in the configuration file.")
       sys.exit(-1)

    if not port:
       logging.warning("PORT not supplied in the configuration file.")
       sys.exit(-1)

    global HOST
    global PORT

    HOST = host
    PORT = int(port)


def handle_files_question(request):
    """ Read the file policy from the database for the server that sent it. 

    Params:
    @request: The request as sent from the server.
    """
    index    = request.find(':')
    hostname = request[index + 1:]

    return register.query_file_policy(hostname)


def handle_size_question(request):
    """ Read the size policy from the database for the server that sent it.

    Params:
    @request: The request as sent from the server.
    """
    index    = request.find(':')
    hostname = request[index + 1:]

    return register.query_size_policy(hostname)



def bind_and_listen():
    """ Bind the server to the socket, and listen for incoming connections. """

    serv = None

    # create the socket
    try:
        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error, v:
        message = "Failed to create a socket: Message is {} and error code is {}"
        errno, errormsg = v  # is a (errno, message) tuple
        message = message.format(errormsg, errno)
        logging.error(message)
        print message
        sys.exit(-1) 

    # bind out socket to the address
    try:
        serv.bind((HOST, PORT)) # the double parens are to create a tuple with one element
    except socket.error, msg:
        message = "Binding of the socket failed. Error Code : {} Message: {}."
        message = message.format(msg[0], msg[1])
        logging.error(message)
        print message
        sys.exit(-2)

    serv.listen(5)    # 5 is the maximum number of queued connections we will allow
    logging.info("Server is now listening on port %d" % (PORT,))

    # we have the try block here only to facilitate the finally block
    # that follows, so that we can reliably close the database everytime
    # we have to close the program, but we don't have an exception raised
    # everytime a client disconnects, the db is closed, and the networking 
    # module attempts to use the cursor of the expired connection.
    try:
        while True:
            conn, addr = serv.accept() 
            hostname   = None
            output     = str()

            # this is the code handling the first policy question, regarding files
            # 256 bytes should be enough to specify the question and hostname
            res    = conn.recv(256)
            output = res

            if output.startswith('files'):
                files = handle_files_question(output)
                conn.send(str(files))

            # reset the output string
            output = str()

            # repeat the above procedure for the size policy question
            res    = conn.recv(256)
            output = res

            if output.startswith('size'):
                size = handle_size_question(output)
                conn.send(str(size))

            # reset the output string
            output = str()

            # handle the rest of the data that the client sends
            # (mainly, the clients and domains lists)
            while True:
                res = conn.recv(1024)
                if not res:
                    break
                output += res

            # at this point, we assume that we have the full output string
            # so we will split it to a list of strings representing the json
            # representation of our clients
            output        = output.split('---')
            domains_index = output.index('Domains_list')

            clients = output[0:domains_index - 1]  # -1 to compensate for a newline in the list
            print clients
            domains = output[domains_index + 1:-1]

            hostname = output[0].split()[1]
            clients  = clients[2:-1] # ignoring the hostname and the Clients_list delimiter

            for client in clients:
                jason = json.loads(client)
                client            = cl_data.Client(jason['client_id'], jason['login'], jason['pname'], jason['email'])
                client.files      = jason['files']
                client.size       = jason['size']
                client.size_human = jason['size_human']
                client.domains    = jason['domains']
                client.domain_num = jason['domain_num']
                client_list.append(client)

            # the code below seems to prevent the problem?
            #for client in client_list:
            #    print client.pname

            for domain in domains:
                jason = json.loads(domain)
                domain = cl_data.DomainName(jason['domain_id'], jason['name'], jason['client_id'])
                domain_list.append(domain)


            conn.close()
            register.update_clients(hostname, client_list)
            register.update_domains(hostname, domain_list)
            logging.info("Connection from %s is terminated." % (addr,))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        message  = "\nCtrl + C was pressed, and an interruption signal has been registered."
        message += " Terminating the server now."
        logging.info(message)
        print message
    finally:
        register.close_connection()
```

All well and good at this point. After I am finished with the loop I use the `client_list` to update an SQL database with this code:

```
register.update_clients(hostname, client_list)
```

The thing is, if I add something like `print len(client_list)` before the above code, I am getting `1` as a result, unless I do something like:

```
for client in client_list:
    print client.email
```

in which case, I get the list with the whole number of objects that should be in it (about 180 or so).

From the above, I am gathering that the list appending gets optimized out for some reason that I can not comprehend, unless I force the list to be iterated immediately after the first loop has ended. Does anyone else have any insight on this? Is this standard behavior and I am doing something wrong? Is this a bug or something?

This is `python 2.7.9` on `debian 8 (jessie)` according to the interpreter and `/etc/os-release`.

(I know I could use the `dis` module to investigate it further, but the way the module is written presents me with some `ImportError`s when I try to import it to a python interpreter)

Comment: Python does **not** do any kind of optimization (it can't. It's too hard to keep track of everything considering how dynamic it is. It will only simplify literal expressions). Please provide some more code. The loop you have shown seems correct and without more context we cannot say anything except making wild guesses.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ok, hold on for a sec, I will try to provide you with more code.

Comment: @Bakuriu I updated the question with the whole module.

Comment: Please try to keep examples minimal, otherwise you may just get a lot of TLDR

Comment: @firelynx I added minimal code that reproduced the error, and I was asked for more. The next logical thing to do was to show the code of the module, and highlight the relevant section.

Comment: You say that the `print clients` always show all the items but only added that loop they get inserted into `client_list`? Looking at the code it doesn't seem that anything fancy is going on.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes indeed. This is extremely frustrating for me. Adding the code that I have commented out seems to be fixing the issue, and I could always find something similar, but it seems like an extremely hacky result, and I want to know what's going on.

Comment: Please insert `print client_list` before and after the problematic line, and let us know what's shown.

Comment: “getting 1 as a result” of what? Does `update_clients` return the number of clients updated? If so, perhaps it skips clients according to some logic which is affected by evaluating `client.email` (e.g. if it’s a property)?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you need to rework your network-code, you assume TCP/IP-sockets to be message-based where in fact they are stream-based. But that's for another day. There is absolutely no way your described behaviour can occur unless you are multi-threaded and do something fancy in  register.update_clients. Also, is client_list really supposed to be a global variable which is ever-growing? I would expect it to be local.